# Exception message is not printed when using WebDriverWait from Selenium through Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, exception, timeoutexception

I am able to see exception message for if xpath is in `try-except()` block as `self.driver.find_element_by_xpath()`.But when I add explicit wait to element,the error message is blank, if the xpath is not present or wrong.

How do I print the error message in except block?
If I run this , for 1st one, able to prent e, next one is blank

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

try:
    input_element=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='q123']")
    input_element.send_keys('Name')
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

try:
    ip_ele=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//input[@name='q123']")))
    ip_ele.send_keys('Name')
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: Are you sure that there is no typo in `WebWebDriverWait`?

Comment: Please edit your question and properly format your code. As it is, it's really hard to read.

Comment: JaSON, the script is working perfectly if the xpath is correct. But I am not able to raise the error message if I just change the xpath with some wrong input, to test error message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43922933/in-python-selenium-how-do-i-set-the-error-messages-for-a-wait/47030390#47030390

Answer (score 3):

When you use `find_element_by_*` and incase no element is found [NoSuchElementException](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/common/selenium.common.exceptions.html#selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException) is thrown.

But if you induce [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) in conjunction with [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) on failure [TimeoutException](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/common/selenium.common.exceptions.html#selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException) is thrown.

At this point, it is worth to mention that you should always catch the desired exception i.e. either `NoSuchElementException` or `TimeoutException` but **not** the base exception i.e. `Exception` to keep your tests clean.

A simple test to observe the `NoSuchElementException` and `TimeoutException` in details:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException

  chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  chrome_options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
  try:
      driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='q123']").send_keys("user10391084")
  except NoSuchElementException as nse:
      print(nse)
      print("-----")
      print(str(nse))
      print("-----")
      print(nse.args)
      print("=====")

  try:
      WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//input[@name='q123']"))).send_keys("user10391084")
  except TimeoutException as toe:
      print(toe)
      print("-----")
      print(str(toe))
      print("-----")
      print(toe.args)
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@name='q123']"}
    (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.100)

  -----
  Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@name='q123']"}
    (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.100)

  -----
  ('no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@name=\'q123\']"}\n  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.100)', None, None)
  =====
  Message: 

  -----
  Message: 

  -----
  ('', None, None)
  ```

---

### Conclusion

You can see from the *Console Output* through the **message** part of the exception is properly defined for **`NoSuchElementException`** but the **message** part is not defined for **`TimeoutException`**. Hence it comes blank.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. He stated in his question `when I add explicit wait to element,the error message is blank` and you explained a lot of stuff and still printed an blank error message when an explicit wait is caught.

Comment: Yea, I also tried with NoSuchElementException and TimeoutException, and there was no output. I want to print the error message when I am using the Explicit wait.

Comment: @pdas Did you really take some time to read the answer atleast once by now?

Comment: @DebanjanB As per your console output for 2nd try-exception block when you print (toe.args) it prints : ('', None, None). But I want to print ('no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@name=\'q123\']"}\n  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.100)', None, None) as error message

Comment: You need to read the answer right from line no. 1. `find_element_by_*` raises `NoSuchElementException` where the message is defined but `WebDriverWait` raises `TimeoutException` where the message is not defined. So you see _blank_

Comment: I understood what you said. My question was that only. How can I print error message while using WebDriverWait. I know, if I use find_element_by_xpath then it will give me the error message.

Comment: @pdas It's not defined still now. Selenium clients need to implement the message first then you can retrieve

Comment: Thank u @DebanjanB. As of now in my code I am using self.driver.find to print the error message and WebDriverWait as explicit wait. Any other option you suggest?

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you mean by _...I am using self.driver.find to print..._, I don't think you can do anything more unless the message for _TimeoutException_ gets defined within the _Selenium-Python_ clients.